# What does the minimum number of nodes in an AzureML compute cluster imply?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

When defining an AzureML compute cluster in the AzureML Studio there is a setting that relates to the minimum number of nodes:

> Azure Machine Learning Compute can be reused across runs. The compute
> can be shared with other users in the workspace and is retained
> between runs, automatically scaling nodes up or down based on the
> number of runs submitted, and the max_nodes set on your cluster. The
> min_nodes setting controls the minimum nodes available.

(From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-attach-compute-cluster?tabs=python).)

I do not understand what *min_nodes* actually is. Is it the number of nodes that the cluster will keep allocated even when idle (i.e. something one might want to speed start-up time)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a better explanation, under a tooltip in the AzureML Studio

> To avoid charges when no jobs are running, set the minimum nodes to 0.
> This setting allows Azure Machine Learning to de-allocate the compute
> nodes when idle. Any higher value will result in charges for the
> number of nodes allocated.

So it is the minimum number of nodes allocated, even when the cluster is idle.